# Django showing {% block title %} if {% content.meta_title %}

Tags: django, django-templates

I need help with displaying django template block.

In base.html I have block with default value.

`<title>{% block title %}Default Title{% endblock %}</title>`

In page.html I have if statement with a block inside.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% if homeContent.meta_title %}
  {% block title %}Title for this Page{% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

Currently content.meta_title is None. However, in rendered html the title is shown as:

`<title>Title for this Page</title>`

I have tried to have different conditions like != '' or != None. But it still does not work. Please help me to find way around. I am confused.

Comment: @Ffion Yes! that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Put if tag inside the title tag like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
    {% if homeContent.meta_title %}
        Title for this Page
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```